# Problem setup cluster elasticsearch, alway return 1 node, what's wrong config?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 servers with ips:

> server-1: xxx.xxx.xxx.102
>
> serverr-2: xxx.xxx.xxx.251
>
> server-3: xxx.xxx.xxx.34

Elasticsearch was installed on all server.
and also add firewall rule for all:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9200/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9300/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Elastic config on servers:

server-1:

```
cluster.name: cluster-mode
node.name: node1
node.master: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.34", "xxx.xxx.xxx.251", "xxx.xxx.xxx.102"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

server-2:

```
cluster.name: cluster-mode
node.name: node2
node.master: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.34", "xxx.xxx.xxx.251", "xxx.xxx.xxx.102"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

server-3:

```
cluster.name: cluster-mode
node.name: node3
node.master: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.34", "xxx.xxx.xxx.251", "xxx.xxx.xxx.102"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

I have reboot elastic on all server and check cluster health

curl -XGET http://xxx.xxx.xxx.102:9200/_cluster/health?pretty

but always return 1 node

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "cluster-mode",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 0,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

Where did I configure the wrong?
need help.
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch are you running?

Comment: The nodes can't discover each other and thus can't build a cluster. Please inspect and share relevant logs of the nodes which indicate why they can't find their peers.

Comment: All your servers are in different networks, the machines can communicate with each other? Also, which version are you running ? Some configurations changed in the last versions.

Comment: thanks for comments, I'm using elasticsearch version 7.5 (current is latest version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch now uses a method called [cluster bootstrapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html) to form the cluster. For this to happen when starting up the cluster for the first time you have to provide set of initial master nodes that will for the cluster and also provide the list of seed hosts which are master eligible nodes and their vote decides the master election.

Therefore replace the following:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.34", "xxx.xxx.xxx.251", "xxx.xxx.xxx.102"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

by the following properties:

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node1", "node2", "node3"]
discovery.seed_hosts: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.34", "xxx.xxx.xxx.251", "xxx.xxx.xxx.102"]
```

Comment: Thank @Opster ES Ninja Nishant, I've changed config, but still return 1 node. curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "cluster-mode",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,

Comment: @quyet If there is no production data indexed then delete `data` folder from the nodes and then restart the nodes.

Comment: Thank @Opster ES Ninja Nishant, clear all data working with new config cluster bootstrapping.